# Good or bad form? Answering a question using another Stack Overflow post

Tags: discussion

Please review Siddharth Rout's comment to my answer here:

[VBA Function to exclude parts of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26788989/vba-function-to-exclude-parts-of-a-string/26790150?noredirect=1#comment42156375_26790150)

[image]

I'm irritated that he gave me a downvote and feel like he treated me rudely, but that's really neither here nor there. I've answered questions with other posts in the past because I felt like the asker may not have been aware of an alternate solution to their problem. People tend not to know the entirety of the subject which they are asking, else they wouldn't be asking.

To avoid bad form, shall I avoid this practice in the future?

Comment: As a side note, I don't think he was being rude in this particular instance. He stated something that you shouldn't do, a better way to do it and an alternative way as well. He didn't say anything offensive, nor was being rude (he even said please) in my opinion. While there is always a way to tell things in a nicer way, it doesn't scale.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Posting an answer and linking to a relevant SE post is fine as long as you add something substantial to your answer.

However, if you don't really add much (here I don't think you did) then it should be a comment and possibly closed as a dupe (if appropriate).

If you link to an answer then give a much better explanation, better code example, etc... then I think it's fine to do this.

Answer (score 10):

@Siddharth Rout's comment was completely on point. Link-only answers; even those to posts within SO, are not answers. You need to include the relevant part of the post (make sure to cite!) with the link.

You could also post it as a comment. In many cases (though not this one from what I can see) another post's answer answering the given question means its a duplicate, so you could flag it (or VTC) as such.

As an aside, that comment didn't seem remotely rude. It was remarkably similar to the pro-forma comment for link-only answers.

Comment: Thank you.  I tend not to downvote people's posts or responses except in rare cases, so I took it personally.  It's not intuitive to me that link-only answers aren't kosher.

Comment: @n8. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer for more info on Link-Only answers. And remember, a user can downvote for any reason; at least he left a comment (assuming it was his downvote). You should learn to not take it personally.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for something like that.  Although the examples provided there are egregious, it gives some impression of the house rules.

Comment: @n8.: "I tend not to downvote people's posts or responses except in rare cases" - then you're not doing it right. Poor quality questions or answers *should be downvoted* - it's the entire basis for all of the [se] sites. Upvote good questions/answers, downvote bad ones. It's the design of everything here. If you're not downvoting as well as upvoting, you're not participating properly.

Comment: @KenWhite good and bad are subjective.  I see many contributions as constructive, adding dimension to the knowledge base.  In most cases I see downvotes as heavy-handed.  A difference of philosophy, I suppose, and the source of my discontent.

Comment: @n8. Just remember that not all users share the same voting "quality threshold". You, like everyone else, are free to vote however you wish (apart from fraud of course).

Comment: @n8.: If you can read 10 random questions at SO and not find at least one deserving of a downvote, you have a very specific tag full of miracle posters. Let me know what that tag is, because it's got to be a really rare topic.

Comment: @n8: Yes I did downvote. But at the same time I left a detailed comment so you knew why was I downvoting :) I am sorry if it sounded rude but trust me that wasn't the intention.

Answer (score 8):

You shouldn't answer such question at all because it appears to be a dupe. You should flag it for closure as duplicate. If you don't feel it is a dupe, post a comment, stating that this question may be related.

Comment: True, but this one doesn't seem like a duplicate.

Comment: I don't see how this could be a duplicate since he's asking for very specific advice.

Comment: @n8.: Even if the question is extremely localized, a properly scoped (meaning broader, in that case) question is still a proper duplicate target. (Did not look at that specific example yet.)

Comment: @n8. If you feel that posting a link to the other question is entirely sufficient as an answer, and that no other information is needed then you obviously *do* feel that it is a duplicate.  The *definition* of a duplicate is a question that is answered merely by directing the user to the existing question.  If you don't feel that the linked post alone answers the question then why did you post an answer with only that link?

Comment: @Servy good point.

Comment: Any idea what a sub-50 should do in this situation?